# Show that there exists $z_n$ which converge to $z_0$ such that $f(z_n) \rightarrow a$ for an essential singularity

Tags: complex-analysis

Fix $a \in \Bbb C$ and suppose $f$ has an essential singularity at $z_0$. Show that there exists $z_n$ which converge to $z_0$ such that $f(z_n) \rightarrow a$

My work:  Suppose $f$ has an isolated singularity at $z_0$. Let $f$ is analytic on punctured disk $\Delta^{*}(z_0,\epsilon)$ for some $\epsilon >0$ . Then for all $\delta < \epsilon$,  $f(\Delta^{*}(z_0,\delta))$ is dense in $\Bbb C$. 
 And so, we have $f(\Delta ^{*} (z_0,1/n)) \cap B(a,1/n)$ is non-empty whenever $1/n <\delta$. Pick a point $w_n$ in this. Then $|w_n-a|<1/n$ and $w_n$ is of the form $f(z_n)$ with $z_n \in \Delta ^{*} (z_0,1/n)$. Hence $f(z_n) \to a$ and $z_n \to z_0$.

Did miss anything? I appreciate your kind help. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f(\Delta (z_0,1/n)) \cap B(a,1/n)$ is non-empty whenever $1/n <\delta$. Pick a point $w_n$ in this. Then $|w_n-a|<1/n$ and $w_n$ is of the form $f(z_n)$ with $z_n \in \Delta (z_0,1/n)$. Hence $f(z_n) \to a$ and $z_n \to z_0$.

Comment: I have updated solution above. Still did I miss anything? I assume u mean  $\Delta ^{*}(z_0,1/n)$!

Comment: Yes, I meant $\Delta^{*}$. You have copied my proof perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

I see you are using *Casorati-Weierstrass' theorem* to prove the claim. You can construct $z_n$ inductively as follows:

Let $\delta_1=\varepsilon/2$. By Casorati-Weierstrass' theorem $f\big(\mathbb D(z_0,\delta_1)\setminus\{z_0\}\big)$ is dense in $\mathbb C$. In particular then this set contains
 some complex number in $\mathbb D(a,1)$, so we may pick
 $$
 z_1\in\mathbb D(z_0,\delta_1)\setminus\{z_0\}\ \text{ with }\ |f(z_1)-a|<1.
 $$
 Take $\delta_2=\min(|z_1-z_0|,\delta_1/2)$. The same argument as above but with $\delta_2$ produces
$$
 z_2\in\mathbb D(z_0,\delta_2)\setminus\{z_0\}\ \text{ with }\ |f(z_2)-a|<1/2.
 $$
 Notice that $|z_2-z_0|<\delta_2\leq|z_1-z_0|$, so $z_2\neq z_1$.
 Take $\delta_3=\min(|z_2-z_0|, \delta_2/2)$. Again we get
 $$
 z_3\in\mathbb D(z_0,\delta_3)\setminus\{z_0\}\ \text{ with }\ |f(z_3)-a|<1/3.
 $$
 and $z_3\not\in\{z_1,z_2\}$ because $|z_3-z_0|<\delta_3\leq|z_2-z_0|\leq|z_1-z_0|.$

Iterating this process produces an *infinite* sequence $\{z_n\}_{n\in\mathbb N}$ in $\mathbb D(z_0,\varepsilon)\setminus\{z_0\}$ satisfying
$$
z_n\in\mathbb D(z_0,\delta_n)\setminus\{z_0\}\ \text{ and }\ |f(z_n)-a|<1/n.
$$
Clearly $f(z_n)\to a$. Moreover, by construction, we have
$$
\delta_n\leq\frac{\delta_{n-1}}2\leq\frac{\delta_{n-2}}{2^2}\leq\ldots\leq\frac{\delta_1}{2^{n-1}}=\frac{\varepsilon}{2^n}\to0\ \text{ as }\ n\to\infty
$$
and so $z_n\to z_0$ as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: Nice and thorough answer. Minor nitpick: $\delta_{n+1}=\min(|z_{n}-a|,\delta_n/2)$ is unnecessarily complicated, in my opinion. It's enough with $\delta_{n+1}=\delta_n/2$ or $\delta_{n}=\varepsilon/2^n$. There is no need to force $z_n$ to move _monotonically_ closer to $z_0$ as $n$ grows.

Comment: @Arthur There was a typo (now corrected) in my answer. I meant to say ‘$z_0$’ instead of ‘$a$’ when defining $\delta_n$. The reason why I define $\delta_n$ as a minimum is to guarantee that we don’t pick the same $z_n$ more than one time. Clearly there is no need for that since we are going to get an infinite sequence anyway, but this way it is explicit that there are no repetitions in the sequence of the $z_n$’s and so that it is an infinite sequence.

Comment: A sequence can have repeated terms without any issues. Even an infinite sequence. A sequence is not just the set of its terms, after all. Also, you can't keep picking the same $z_n$ indefinitely, as eventually the $\delta$'s will catch up (even with one of my definitions), and force you to pick a new value.

Comment: @Arthur Yes, absolutely, the sequence of $z_n$’s is necessarily infinite as long as $\delta_n\to0$. I just found it easier to require a minimum and make it explicit that the sequence of $z_n$’s is infinite than to explain that the condition $\delta_n\to0$ forces $\{z_n\}$ to be an infinite sequence (English is not my mother tongue). Anyway, thank you for pointing that out, it will probably be helpful for future readers and maybe for the OP as well!